# Metasploit Pivoting on loopback?

Tags: metasploit

I'm pen-testing a Windows 7 machine, and have access to a limited remote shell.

I can see there's a vulnerable SMB service running on the machine's loopback, but it's not available externally.

Is there any way I can run a metasploit exploit over the session I already have, to access this service?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. type in metasploit `use post/windows/manage/autoroute` then `set SESSION 1` (1 is the session that you have meterpreter on) `SET subnet 192.xxx.xxx.0` (your pen-test subnet) type `run` check if it works with `route print`.This makes the traffic goes internally
.

If all it's ok, you can use your session of "Victim 1" to send commands internally to "Victim 2" the packets would be like this: 
You > Victim 1 > Victim 2

Remember to set LHOST in next exploit to be your Victim 1 Address.